# Multithread server client C

Tags: c, multithreading, sockets

Hello i have some problem with threads and client and server implementation, i created 2 clients that write on the socket infinite numbers.
to managed the 2  client in the sever.c i create threads everytime a new connection is accept.
it runs but if one client run it works but if i run the second one the first interrupted itself; how can i printf alternately ?
i would like : G1
                G2
                G1 etc

G1.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <netdb.h> 
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h> 
#include <errno.h> 
#include <signal.h>
#include <time.h> 
void error(char *msg)
{
    perror(msg);
    exit(0);
}
struct message {  //dichiarazione struct
 time_t timestamp;  
 char g;  //process identifier
 int x;
};
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  int sockfd, portno, n,i;
  struct message m1;
  struct sockaddr_in serv_addr;
  struct hostent *server;
  struct timespec delay;
  delay.tv_sec = 1;
  delay.tv_nsec = 0; //in microseconds
  long int offset=1000000;
  struct timeval tv;
  char buffer[256];
  if (argc < 3) {
    fprintf(stderr,"usage %s hostname port\n", argv[0]);
    exit(0);
  }
  portno = atoi(argv[2]);
  sockfd = socket(AF_UNIX, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
  if (sockfd < 0) 
    error("ERROR opening socket");
  server = gethostbyname(argv[1]);
  if (server == NULL) {
    fprintf(stderr,"ERROR, no such host\n");
    exit(0);
  }
  bzero((char *) &serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr));
  serv_addr.sin_family = AF_UNIX;
  bcopy((char *)server->h_addr, 
  (char *)&serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr,
  server->h_length);
  serv_addr.sin_port = htons(portno);

  if (connect(sockfd,(struct sockaddr *)&serv_addr,sizeof(serv_addr)) < 0) 
    error("ERROR connecting");
    while(1){
    m1.timestamp=time(NULL);
    m1.x=i;
    m1.g=getpid();

    n = write(sockfd,&m1,sizeof(m1));
    if (n < 0) 
      error("ERROR writing to socket");
    i++;
    delay.tv_nsec=offset+rand()%offset;
    nanosleep(&delay,NULL);
  }

  return 0;
}`
```

R.c(server)

```
#include<stdio.h>

#include<stdlib.h>

#include<sys/socket.h>

#include<netinet/in.h>

#include<string.h>

#include <arpa/inet.h>

#include <fcntl.h> // for open

#include <unistd.h> // for close

#include<pthread.h>
struct message {  //dichiarazione struct
  time_t timestamp;  
  char g;  //process identifier
  int x;
};
struct message client_message;

char buffer[1024];

static void * socketThread(void *arg)
{ 
  while(1) {
    int newSocket = *((int *)arg);

    recv(newSocket , &client_message , sizeof(client_message), 0);

    printf("message %d  %d %ld\n",client_message.x,client_message.g,client_message.timestamp);
    fflush(stdout);
    sleep(1);
  }
}

int main(){

  int serverSocket, newSocket;

  struct sockaddr_in serverAddr;

  struct sockaddr_storage serverStorage;

  socklen_t addr_size;

  //Create the socket. 

  serverSocket = socket(AF_UNIX, SOCK_STREAM, 0);

  // Configure settings of the server address struct

  // Address family = Internet 

  serverAddr.sin_family = AF_UNIX;

  //Set port number, using htons function to use proper byte order 

  serverAddr.sin_port = htons(6005);

  //Set IP address to localhost 

  serverAddr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("127.0.0.1");

  //Set all bits of the padding field to 0 

  memset(serverAddr.sin_zero, '\0', sizeof serverAddr.sin_zero);

  //Bind the address struct to the socket 

  bind(serverSocket, (struct sockaddr *) &serverAddr, sizeof(serverAddr));

  //Listen on the socket, with 40 max connection requests queued 

  if(listen(serverSocket,50)!=0)
  {
    printf("Error\n");
    return -1;
  }
  printf("Listening\n");

  pthread_t tid[60];

  int i = 0;

  while(1)
  {
        //Accept call creates a new socket for the incoming connection

        addr_size = sizeof serverStorage;

        newSocket = accept(serverSocket, (struct sockaddr *) &serverStorage, &addr_size);

        //for each client request creates a thread and assign the client request to it to process

        //so the main thread can entertain next request

        if( pthread_create(&tid[i], NULL, socketThread, &newSocket) != 0 )
           printf("Failed to create thread\n");
        else
          ++i;
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Thanks !

Comment: You pass the socket as a pointer. Then in the `while` you re-read that pointer, so when the 2nd socket connects, the first socket it now using the 2nd one. Solution: don't pass a pointer to the thread. Or, move `int newSocket = *((int *)arg);` to before the `while` loop.

Comment: @JohnnyMopp Thanks! Perfect Answer, now it works. thanks, thanks

Answer (score 0):

As I understand in server code in thread function *socketThread()* you get value of socket descriptor on each iteration. But when you accept new connection in this address writes new value of new socket descriptor. And after that each thread gets data only from last socket.

**You should pass in *socketThread()* socket descriptor by value (not by a pointer)!**